# ArrayList of Objects from a different class - null pointer error

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public void populatePrizeArraylist()
{
    ArrayList <Prize> prizeArrayList = new ArrayList <Prize>();
    // The name of the file which we will read from   
    File filename = new File("prizes.txt");

    try 
    {   
        // Prepare to read from the file, using a Scanner object
        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(filename);

        Scanner parser = new Scanner(inputFile);
        // Read each line until end of file is reached
        while (parser.hasNextLine())
        {
            // Read an entire line, which contains all the details for 1 prize
            String readFile = parser.nextLine();
            String delimiter = ","; 
            String[] fileList = readFile.trim().split(delimiter);

            Prize newPrize = new Prize();

            newPrize.setPrizeName(fileList[0]);
            newPrize.setPrizeWorth(Integer.parseInt(fileList[1]));
            newPrize.setPrizeCost(Integer.parseInt(fileList[2]));

            this.prizeArrayList.add(newPrize);

        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have created a new ArrayList then a new object and set some values to the name variable of that object but when I try to add that object to my arraylist i get a null point exception error

Comment: Are you sure you get a run-time exception? Your code, as it is, will not compile since you are trying to invoke a non-existent `setGoodName()` method on the `ArrayList` instead of your object `newItem`

Comment: hi @kaykay i have put more of the code, are you able to work out what is wrong

Comment: This code is totally different from the snippet you had posted earlier. Please consider making your question clearer. Imagine if someone asks you to debug some code, what information would you expect from them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your code right.
You are populating your array list inside a void function.
Array list is created inside that function locally.
If you don't return that array list somewhere that array list is deleted after your function endas.

Aditional advice, use constructors it is bad habit to create a class through a default constructor then set its properties to some value through methods.

Comment: thanks @Spidey definitely learning a lot here. So what would you recommend instead then?

Comment: @Tarinkot Use custom constructors they will allow you to add values for your properties inside a parameter. In case you are not familiar with them I recommend a good tutorial page on java.

Comment: @Tarinkot regarding the main  issue I recommend returning your array list wherever you need to use it.

Answer (score 3):

This variable declaration is inside the method scope

```
ArrayList <Prize> prizeArrayList = new ArrayList <Prize>();
```

and you are trying to add elements using

```
this.prizeArrayList.add(newPrize);
```

so I am sure there is a class level variable "prizeArrayList" defined which is not yet initialized and you are trying to add to it and getting NPE.

You have to use

```
prizeArrayList.add(newPrize);
```

Comment: how can I initialise it?

Comment: looking at your method, you don't want to add to class level variable. Just remove "this" from the line where you add the newPrize to prizeArrayList.

Comment: ok that worked but now I can not access it from any other method as the prizeArrayList is not a class level variable, it just creates it inside the method scope and then disappears?

Comment: Then let's initialize your class level variable. Use `new ArrayList <Prize>();` to assign an empty list to your class level variable. You don't need the method scope `prizeArrayList` so just go and remove that line from method (the 1st one).

Comment: use `this.prizeArrayList.add(newPrize);`. Your original code will work.

Answer (score 2):

```
goodsArrayList.setGoodName("Pants");
goodsArrayList.add(newItem);
```

is wrong because you need to call `setGoodName()` to `newItem`
try this:

```
newItem.setGoodName("Pants");
goodsArrayList.add(newItem);
```

Comment: hi jake, it compiles ok but i get a null pointer exception error